# MongoSQLd not starting on Windows

Tags: mongodb, odbc, mongodb-biconnector

I'm very new user of Mongo and I'm trying to enable MongoDB connector for BI.

I want to change my connect address, but it only connects to 127.0.0.1...

I made a config file (net:
bindIp: '192.168.**.**'
port: 27**8)
I follow steps describe into https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/tutorial/install-bi-connector/ but when doing net start mongosql I got the following error message:

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Connector for BI\2.14\bin>net start mongosql
The MongoSQL Service service is starting.

The MongoSQL Service service could not be started.

A service specific error occurred: 1.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3547.

How can I connect to my server IP and make DSN by this mongosql?

Comment: Check the logfile. Location is set in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

My problem Solved :  [Go to this link](https://medium.com/qimi-techblog/connecting-mongodb-hosted-in-mongo-atlas-with-powerbi-including-m0-clusters-ae02fbef0c7d)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is path from log file is empty, you should change it in mongosqld-config.yml.

```
    systemLog:
      ## The path to the file where log output will be written to.
      ## Defaults to stderr.
      # path: <string>
      quiet: false
      ## 0|1|2 - Verbosity of the log output, this is overridden if `quiet`         is true.
      verbosity: 1
      # logAppend: false
```